# Image view shape as a vawe

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, imageview

I try so hard to get custom shape of Image view. I want to make it looks like a vawe, but its kinda hard. Does anyone know any library, or can give an advise how to create custom ImageView whitch looks like vawe?

Im looking for something like this :

[image]

Comment: If you have the shape already, you can also consider masking your image when drawing it. Create a paint with `maskingPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));` and draw your mask over the existing image

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43468340/1967021